# Updating a column if condition is met with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame to work on and I am performing several checks.

I am checking whether the repeating values under the columns "A", "B" and "C" present the same number but with opposite sign under column D.

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | AAA | 123 | 0.01 | comment to be replaced |
| 2222 | BBB | 456 | 5 | comment to be replaced |
| 3333 | CCC | 789 | 10 | don't do anything |
| 1111 | AAA | 123 | -0.01 | comment to be replaced |
| 2222 | BBB | 456 | -5 | comment to be replaced |
| 3333 | CCC | 789 | -9 | don't do anything |

Please see my code below. When I try replacing the comment under the column "E", it does not work. I am sure that I am doing something wrong.
I am fully aware of the fact that I haven't written the code in the most efficient way, I am still a newbie. Would you be able to help me with both a more efficient way to achieve this and, out of curiosity, how this could be achieved if I decided to keep using this "non-efficient" way?

Thank you.

```
for i in range(0, len(df)-1):
    for j in range(i+1, len(df)):
        if (df['A'][i] == df['A'][j]) & (df['B'][i] == df['B'][j]) & (df['C'][i] == df['C'][j]) & (df['D'][i] + df['D'][j] = 0) :
            df['E'][i] = 'it works!'
```

Comment: Can there be more/less than two rows per unique values of `A, B, C`?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @ShubhamSharma. Yes, if there are more/ less columns, the comment will vary.

Comment: Please do not edit the question such that it invalidates existing answer. It is better asking a new one instead. Read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332820/what-to-do-when-someone-answers-dont-be-a-chameleon-dont-be-a-vandal) and related posts for more information of good practices

Comment: @DaniB Please consider adding a new question instead and rollback you current edits because your latest edits completely invalidates the existing answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can `group` the dataframe on columns `A`, `B`, `C` along with series of absolute values in column `D` then `transform` the column `D` using `sum` (*because if the pairs have opposite sign then there sum must be zero*) to check for the presence of pairs having same magnitude but opposite sign

```
df['E'] = df.groupby(['A', 'B', 'C', df['D'].abs()])['D'].transform('sum').eq(0)
```

---

```
      A    B    C      D      E
0  1111  AAA  123   0.01   True
1  2222  BBB  456   5.00   True
2  3333  CCC  789  10.00  False
3  1111  AAA  123  -0.01   True
4  2222  BBB  456  -5.00   True
5  3333  CCC  789  -9.00  False
```

Comment: Brilliant! And what if I also wanted to update the comment under the column "E" for the rows where the condition is met?

Comment: @DaniB We could use `np.where`. Please check `df['E'] = np.where(df['E'], 'it works', 'it doesnt work')`

Comment: This answer is very clever if it is clear that there can only be 1 positive and 1 negative value. It gets unstable however if there are uneven entries, or multiple A, B , C combinations. E.g. try to add `2222 BBB 456 -1 comment to be replaced`to your sample.

Comment: Thanks for you comment @Andreas but IMHO it should still work even if there are uneven enteries. because here we are grouping additionally on the absolute values of column `D` so the uneven entries wont find a pair and transformed result will not be equal to zero in any case.

Comment: @Andreas that's a good point. My next goal would be to find the pairs that added together (that meet the condition) give the unmatched amount.

Comment: @ShubhamSharma would you have any idea on how this can be achieved?

Comment: @DaniB Lets discuss [`here`](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228691/ds5)

Comment: @ShubhamSharma what I mean by uneven is imagine 3 duplicates the first has +5 in D the other two have -5 in D. This the sum would therefore be 5 and the `.transform('sum').eq(0) `would not equal to True for all 3 entries.

Answer (score 0):

This works in case you have more than one pair in E or if there is 1 positive and multiple negative and vice versa.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_1 = df[df['D'] >= 0].copy().reset_index()
df_2 = df[df['D'] < 0].copy().reset_index()
df_2['D'] = -df_2['D']

indexes = df_1.merge(df_2, on=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], how='inner')[['index_x', 'index_y']].values.tolist()
indexes = [item for sublist in indexes for item in sublist]

df['E_new'] = np.where(df.index.isin(indexes), 'new comment', df['E'])

print(df)

#       A    B    C      D                       E              E_new
# 0  1111  AAA  123   0.01  comment to be replaced        new comment
# 1  2222  BBB  456   5.00  comment to be replaced        new comment
# 2  3333  CCC  789  10.00       don't do anything  don't do anything
# 3  1111  AAA  123  -0.01  comment to be replaced        new comment
# 4  2222  BBB  456  -5.00  comment to be replaced        new comment
# 5  3333  CCC  789  -9.00       don't do anything  don't do anything
```